# flying within the US with a cactus in carryon

Tags: usa, air-travel, airport-security

I'll be flying domestically within the US from a part of the country where cacti are common to one where they aren't. As a small token gift I'd like to bring a small prickly pear cactus from my yard. These cacti are covered in small spines and could *possibly* be used as a weapon, albeit not a very effective one. I won't be checking any bags so unfortunately it would have to travel in my carryon.

Would it allowed to bring a cactus in my carryon or is it considered a banned item?

I am flying from Colorado to Logan International in Boston. The flight is domestic so I wouldn't go through Customs.

Comment: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all says plants are OK and nothing about cacti, but you can double check with them by using the AskTSA procedure described on that page. Don’t forget to tell us the result!

Comment: A cactus in carry-on will not be a problem on the flight but it might be a problem when you land. Several places do not accept living plants and/or the earth they grow in as diseases may be carried. Even fruit is often not acceptable. Can you please add where you start from and where you fly to, so people can help you with that.

Comment: @Willeke The destination airport is Logan International in Boston. The flight is domestic so I wouldn't go through Customs.

Comment: Some states have an agricultural inspection at the border.  I've seen them in Hawaii (Maui airport) and California (at the Nevada border).  I am fairly certain that there is no such inspection at Logan.

Comment: @phoog I have never seen California do an agricultural inspection at an airport, just at the land borders.

Comment: @Willeke not familiar with the USA, but in NZ/AU the worst-case scenario for something like that, assuming you don't lie to the officer, is that they'll make you throw the cactus away in a quarantine bin - so you don't get to keep the cactus, but you don't lose anything, either.

Comment: Massachusetts prohibits the import of many plants.  See [here](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/massachusetts-prohibited-plant-list) for a list.  You should verify that the plant you wish to import is not on that list.

Comment: Please indicate what states you are flying from and to. For example, if you are flying from Arizona, take a look at pages 44 to 51 of [this document](https://agriculture.az.gov/sites/default/files/Native%20Plant%20Rules%20-%20AZ%20Dept%20of%20Ag.pdf) It lists all of the plants that are protected in Arizona. Most people know Saguaro's are protected, but fewer people know how many other plants are likewise protected. There are no border protections between states, but you still have to pass through security and TSA may or may not know local laws. Then again, you could get a busybody...

Comment: There is a border protection between Arizona and California, between Phoenix and Los Angeles, as you drive into California via I-10, but that type of thing basically doesn't exist in most of the country.

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm flying from Colorado. I edited the question